# How to disable ACLs on ZFS in FreeNAS?

Tags: zfs, access-control-list, truenas

I inherited a FreeNAS installation that I recently upgraded to version 9. I have some ZFS mounts that are mounted like this:

```
data1/data on /mnt/data1/data (zfs, NFS exported, local, nfsv4acls)
data1/lan on /mnt/data1/lan (zfs, NFS exported, local, nfsv4acls)
```

and I am having some permissions problems. I think it has to do with the ACLs, but I am not quite sure. How can I completely disable the ACLs and fallback to the standard Unix style permissions (which are perfectly suitable for my setup) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I remember it is not possible to disable the ACL on ZFS. But you can try to remove any ACL config with `chmod A- filename` "Removing all non-trivial ACEs from a file" Take a look at the [ZFS ACL admin guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/819-5461/ftyxi.html#scrolltoc) it's for Solaris but I guess that the ACL setup is the same.

Comment: Thanks. I fixed my direct problems by mounting the drives as CIFS instead of NFS (only NFS mounts had problems). I guess I have some studying to do in the weekend ;).

Answer (score 2):

setfacl -b removes an acl entry. You can use also use the -R flag for recursion.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to mount the file systems without the `nfsv4acls` option, so the ACLs stay in place but don't get used, instead of deleting them?

Comment: @AndrewSchulman is it? I like your thinking, but I really am super paranoid about my system as it's in production and I'd like to do the right thing the first time :/

Answer (score 0):

Best to remove the ACLS with setfacl -bn, they cause nothing but trouble on NFS shares, and are simply a solution looking for a problem.

Shares without ACLS also have a higher data throughput via the shorter code path, than those with.

Comment: AFAIR `setfacl` should not work on the newer NFSv4 ACLs anymore (at least that is the case in illumos), you must use `chmod` instead (not the GNU version, if that should be installed).